# this.getDomNode() in reapp returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just got started with [reapp](http://reapp.io/). I simply created an app. Once the app was created, I modified the default home.jsx as shown:

```
import { Reapp, React } from 'reapp-kit';

class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='map'></div>
    );
  }

  getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            initialZoom: 8,
            mapCenterLat: 43.6425569,
            mapCenterLng: -79.4073126,
        };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Dom node is ',this.getDomNode());
  }

}

export default Reapp(Home);
```

Now the issue is the `this.getDomNode` which returns the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `React.findDOMNode(this)` instead of `this.getDOMNode()`, [which is deprecated in 0.13.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode) and isn't available on classes that extend `React.Component`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`React.findDOMNode(this)`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode) instead of `getDomNode`,

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='map'></div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Dom node is ', React.findDOMNode(this));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those who are looking for the updated answer for the latest React, here it goes.

React **findDOMNode** API is been moved into a `react-dom` package. You can find the reference [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode).

So use,

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)
```

to get the element.

Thank you.